# How to encrypt connection strings section when debugging

Tags: azure, web-config, connection-string, aspnet-regiis.exe

I need the following setup:

- When debugging my application, I want my `connectionStrings` config section to be encrypted via `aspnet_regiis`
- When publishing the application, connection strings should be normal, unencrypted `<add>` elements, where the value just contains some placeholder text.

My reasoning is:

1. When pushing the code to remote repo, i don't want my debug credentials to be saved there in plaintext (hence the encrypted section)
2. When publishing the app to Azure, I can override the placeholder, unencrypted connection strings from azure portal

Is this possible using config transformations?

The only examples I can find transform individual connection string elements, but I need the entire section to look different depending on debug/release settings.

Appreciate any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with the help of [this useful post](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples):

```
<connectionStrings xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(configProtectionProvider)">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(Type)" />

    <add xdt:Transform="Insert" name="CDSsvcUsername" connectionString="username"/>
    <add xdt:Transform="Insert" name="CDSsvcPassword" connectionString="password"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

So I'm calling `xdt:Transform="Remove"` on the entire `Encrypted` element as well as removing the `configProtectionProvider` attribute on `connectionStrings`.

This only worked after specifying `xdt:Locator` in the remove transformation.